# Adjust column order after joining two data frames

Tags: r

I would like to generate a new data frame that joins both datasets (df1 and df2) below and is in the following column order: n, M1, M1_with_normalization, M2, M2_with_normalization, M3, M3_with_normalization, M4 and M4_with_normalization. How can I do this?

```
df1<- structure(list(n = c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 
32, 33, 34, 35), M1 = c(1L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L), M2 = c(1, 29, 28, 27, 
26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 15, 12, 19, 18, 17, 16, 14, 13, 11, 
10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2), M3 = c(1L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 
26L, 24L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 
14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L), M4 = c(1L, 
29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 
3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -29L))


df2<-structure(list(n= c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 
32, 33, 34, 35), M1_with_normalization = c(29L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 18L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L), M2_with_normalization = c(1L, 
29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 
3L), M3_with_normalization = c(1L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L), M4_with_normalization = c(1L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 
25L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 
13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
29L))
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Are you trying to do it in base, tidyverse, data.table or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the datasets are in the same row order with same dimensions, `cbind` both the datasets and rearrange the column names

```
out <- cbind(df1, df2[-1])[c(rbind(names(df1), names(df2)))[-2]]
```

-output

```
> head(out, 3)
  n M1 M1_with_normalization M2 M2_with_normalization M3 M3_with_normalization M4 M4_with_normalization
1 7  1                    29  1                     1  1                     1  1                     1
2 8 29                     1 29                    29 29                    29 29                    29
3 9 28                     2 28                    28 28                    28 28                    28
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   bind_cols(df2 %>%
                select(-n)) %>%
   relocate(n, sort(names(.)))
```